# How to get Micro Mushrooms in Super Luigi U?

Tags: new-super-luigi-u

In Super Luigi U, what is the most reliable way to obtain a micro mushroom when I need one?

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way to get one is to go to the Layer-Cake Desert and fight the Goomba that is running around the maze of pillars with a Hammer Bro. As far as I'm aware it will give you one for winning 100% of the time.

Another (but less reliable) way to obtain them is to fight the penguin sliding in and out of a pipe in the snow world (the first one before the circle of ice). It will give you either a micro mushroom or a propeller mushroom.

Answer (score 0):

From what I’ve been playing if you hit the flag pole with exactly 66 seconds left on the clock Toad will also give you a blue mushroom.

Comment: Welcome and thanks for contributing. I'm sure the OP will find your input helpful, but it may have been better to post this as a comment, since this doesn't answer the question completely. You may need to [wait to comment until you have sufficient reputation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). Until then, keep on asking and answering good questions!

Answer (score 0):

Rocky Candy Mines-1...
 right when you have your 1st jump. It will be a hidden block that has a mini mushroom on the 1st platform to the left after jumping over the 1st black fuzzy ball monster